# How to stop "Share Your Location" deafault popup in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a webpage which contains map using leaflet. When I open the page then it asks "Share Your location". How can I stop this command, so that nothing pops up even I browse the page from a new machine.

```
var map = L.map("map-container").setView([ 41.5908, -93.6208 ], 7) //latitude, longitude, zoom level
    .locate({
        "setView" : false
    });
```

I have set false to locate.

Comment: Can you share the link of that page?

Comment: It looks like the [Geolocation API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate) has been activated. Have a look if there's anything calling `.locate` on a map object (i.e. `map.locate()`) in the page.

Comment: var map = L.map("map-container").setView([ 41.5908, -93.6208 ], 7) 
  .locate({
   "setView" : false
  });

Comment: so, remove this `.locate({"setView":false})`